# OneToOne Symfomy2&Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-one

I need to save user with his profile fields. I establish relations. User has one Profile, Profile has one User. I add fields to register form. But when I saving object, I get error,
Undefined index: profile in /var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2714 . Where my mistake, please help me. I am newbie)
Here is the code:
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Profile
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="acme_profile")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Profile
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="fio", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $fio;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="birthDate", type="date")
     */
    protected $birthDate;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFio()
    {
        return $this->fio;
    }

    /**
     * @param $fio
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setFio($fio)
    {
        $this->fio = $fio;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBirthDate()
    {
        return $this->birthDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param $birthDate
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBirthDate($birthDate)
    {
        $this->birthDate = $birthDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUser(User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="acme_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Profile", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $profile;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function setProfile(Profile $profile = null)
    {
        $this->profile = $profile;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProfile()
    {
        return $this->profile;
    }
}
```

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // add your custom field
        $builder->add('profile', new ProfileType());
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_user_registration';
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your code, please?

Comment: here is code. i have another problem. i cant get the profile related entity througth $user->getProfile();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the MappedBy and InversedBy as specified in the documentation here : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-side-and-inverse-side

```
 /**
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Profile",        
    mappedBy="user"))
  */
```

and the other side you use :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="profile" cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
```

Comment: that help for me) but i got another problem. cascade={"persist"} saves related profile, but field user_id is  empty, how i can assign this field. and i have another question - how i can assign roles to user manually?

Comment: can i see your controller first, and to assign roles to user you can use an array to get roles from the user like $roles = $user->getRoles() then $roles[] = 'YOUR_ROLE_TOADD' then $user->setRoles($roles)

Comment: i am using FOSUserBundle, and i havent contoller. i think i must ovveride RegisterController like in FOS doc. but i just get errors.

Comment: Yes, you should override the Controller where you edit the profile and that is ProfileController you should read more the documentation of FOSUserBundle if you don't know how to do it, they explain fairly well. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Error: You have requested a non-existent service "fos_user.registration.form.handler". Did you mean one of these: "fos_user.registration.form.factory", "acme_user.registration.form.type", "fos_user.registration.form.type"?
I just copy/paste controller code. I think i need to declare another service like - acme_user.registration.form.type.

Comment: Override the ProfileController of FOSUserBundle if you don't know how to do this, go visit this website if you dont know how  : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md